# Что лучше поставить: двоеточие или тире?

Tags: тире, двоеточие

В предложении «Старый город Евпатории: что ни дом, то история» или лучше «Старый город Евпатории – что ни дом, то история»?

Answer (score 2):

Более подходящим вариантом представляется постановка двоеточия:

***Старый город Евпатории: что ни дом, то история.***

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Выбор знака регулируется правилом:
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189

6. Параллельное употребление двоеточия и тире встречается при обособлении пояснительных и уточняющих членов предложения:  Ср. пунктуационное оформление близких по структуре **заголовков**: *Знакомьтесь: Балуев; Внимание — ребёнок*.

При постановке **двоеточия** интонация предупредительная: голос понижается, делается  подчеркнутая пауза (интонационное предупреждение по Розенталю).  Это более частотный вариант для обозначения **подробного раскрытия темы**.

**При постановке** тире  другая интонация, соответствующая предложению: Внимание – перед вами ребенок. Здесь голос повышается, а пауза менее длительная.  Это скорее заголовок для  **небольшой информационной статьи**.